# OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in .Net Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

Is there any method in .NET framework that is equivalent for method OnModelCreating in.NETcore?

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity("DataAccessLayerInterfaces.Entities.Employee", b =>
...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to define it like this :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<DataAccessLayerInterfaces.Entities>()
                .HasOptional(x => x...)
                .WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x...)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
     ...
}
```